# Quick way of getting the keys in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, syntactic-sugar

Consider the example below:
`m = [{'a':1},{'b':2}]`
I wanted to find a short way of forming a list of the keys in `m`, just like `['a','b']`. What would be the shortest or the easiest way rather than using traditional for loops? Perhaps a syntactic sugar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple double for-loop with list-comprehension should do the trick. Iterate over the list, and for each element in the list, iterate over the keys

```
In [5]: m = [{'a':1},{'b':2}]                                                                                                                                                                                                

In [6]: [k for item in m for k in item]                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[6]: ['a', 'b']
```

If the list has duplicate keys, just convert the final output to a set and then to a list to get unique keys

```
In [19]: m = [{'a':1, 'b':2},{'a':3,'b':4}]                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [20]: r = [k for item in m for k in item]                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [21]: r                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[21]: ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']

In [22]: r = list(set(r))                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [23]: r                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[23]: ['b', 'a']
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use list comprehension, a sintactic sugar of for loops:

```
keys_list = [x for d in m for x in d.keys()]
```

Note that if your dictionaries have keys in common they will be appear more than once in the result.

If you want only unique keys, you can do this:

```
keys_list = list(set(x for d in m for x in d.keys()))
```

Comment: But that does not give a string right? That gives something like `[dict_keys(['a']), dict_keys(['b'])]`, instead of `['a','b']`

Comment: Yea, now i change the answe, sorry.

Comment: You can even write it more simply: `[x for x in d for d in m]` because iterating over a dictionary returns the keys.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know. If you don't mind I edit the post with your suggestion.

Comment: I already have that approach in my answer @dome I think you might want to avoid duplication ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see.

Comment: did you test this code ? @dome

Comment: Just corrected the error.

Comment: Not sure how the last approach gives unique keys, just try it with `m = [{'a':1, 'b':2},{'a':3,'b':4}]`

Comment: You are right, corrected it.

Comment: Cool, +1 for the correction. Could you upvote my answer as well :)

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 2):

1. Extract all dicts keys to a list of lists
2. Convert them to one list by [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.chain)

```
from itertools import chain

a = [{'a': 1, 'c': 2}, {'b': 2}]
b = [d.keys() for d in a]
list(chain(*b))
```

will return:

`['c', 'a', 'b']`

Answer (score 1):

If you want just unique keys do this:

```
m = [{'a':1},{'b':2},{'b':3}]
print({x for d in m for x in d})
```

and this one contains duplicates:

```
print([x for d in m for x in d])
```

Comment: did you test your code? @alireza yazdandoost

Comment: @ncica I edited that :) now it's ok